# JavaScript Game Help: Find the worm

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a browser based game that will place 4 "worms" on a 10 x 10 grid. The user then make guesses as to where he or she thinks the worms may be. The program then tells how many units the guess is from each worm.

For example:

*The program randomly places the worms in the following locations*

Worm 1 is in 2,2

Worm 2 is in 3,9

Worm 3 is in 5,6

Worm 4 is in 1,9

*The browser prompts a guess*

Make a guess: [4,4]

*Now the game reports in the browser how far each worm is from the guess*

Worm 1 is 2.8 units away

Worm 2 is 9.5 units away

Worm 3 is 7.8 units away

Worm 4 is 9 units away

I'd love some advice as to how to start this and what should I use for this. I am a fairly new JS programmer and I still struggle with some of the principles.

Thanks!

Comment: show us what you have tried. Don't ask us to do the work for you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is asked in a way that is unlikely to get answered here. Try editing your question to include some code, including a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Start from defining how to describe worm, should it could be object which some how describes worms position.